# DynamoDB model for IAM user data

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, nosql

I'm collecting IAM user data and storing it in DynamoDB. Now I'm thinking about the best way to store it.

I want to query on:

1. Query on all info about keys and users in an account         --> Define PK ACCOUNT#<account_id>
2. Query on all info about users in an account              --> Define PK ACCOUNT#<account_id> + SK starts with USER
3. Query on all info about access keys in an account        --> Define PK ACCOUNT#<account_id> + SK starts with ACCESSKEY
4. Query on last used key(over all) (e.g. all keys after that date)?
5. Query on a specific access key (over all) (see to who this key belongs) ?
6. Query on all access keys for a specific user?

I was thinking about this as PK/SK structure.

```
PK                      SK                                  
ACCOUNT#account_id      ACCESSKEY#access_key        
ACCOUNT#account_id      USER#user_name
```

But I'm not sure how to handle the last three queries. It feels wrong to create a GSI for lastUsed and to create a GSI for ACCESSKEY#access_key (and then I still don't have a way to find access keys for a specific user).

Any important thoughts I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

I would go with the following design.

#### Table

```
PK: account_id; SK: access_key; Attribute: user_name; Attribute: date_last_used
```

#### LSI (`user_name-index`):

```
SK: user_name
```

#### GSI (`access_key-index`):

```
PK: access_key
```

#### Queries 1 - 3

This would be covered by filtering on the result of:

```
aws dynamodb query \
    --table-name iam-users \
    --key-condition-expression "account_id = :num" \
    --expression-attribute-values  '{":num":{"S":"123456"}}'
```

#### Query 4

Since you are looking for an overall picture, a `scan` of the entire table is justified.

#### Query 5

```
aws dynamodb query \
    --table-name iam-users \
    --index-name access_key-index \
    --key-condition-expression "access_key = :key" \
    --expression-attribute-values  '{":key":{"S":"ASHLJFDHSKJD"}}'
```

#### Query 6

```
aws dynamodb query \
    --table-name iam-users \
    --index-name user_name-index \
    --key-condition-expression "account_id = :num AND user_name = :name" \
    --expression-attribute-values  '{":num":{"S":"123456"}, ":name":{"S":"johndoe"}}'
```

In case you intended to have the same `user_name` to span multiple accounts, create an additional GSI (`user_name-global-index`):

```
PK: user_name
```

This will allow to have Query 6:

```
aws dynamodb query \
    --table-name iam-users \
    --index-name user_name-global-index \
    --key-condition-expression "user_name = :name" \
    --expression-attribute-values  '{":name":{"S":"johndoe"}}'
```